# Random crashes of Java VM in ConcurrentGCThread

Tags: java, jvm, crash, java-6

We have problems with JVMs running internet applications under changing load. This problem comes and goes. One day we see three VMs dying and after that, there is nothing for a week or two. We have not found a pattern yet, found nothing to reproduce or cause it. Also a search in the Sun bug database did not help.

We tried a suggested workaround (-XX:-CMSPermGenPrecleaningEnabled -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled) from https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6354939
Did not help. It seem to just change the thread that causes it... or at least make us believe so.

Also an upgrade to 1.6.0_13 did not help and the bug request to Sun never returned a response.

So my question is, has anyone seen that or has an idea what to look for? Could this be related to OS libraries?

Edited: OS is Linux, OpenSuse running on AMD cpus (Linux 2.6.18.8-0.1-dw #3 SMP Thu Mar 15 01:21:48 GMT 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x062c75f5, pid=6667, tid=1090374560
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (11.2-b01 mixed mode linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# V [libjvm.so+0x2c75f5]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

--------------- T H R E A D ---------------

Current thread (0x081ddc00): ConcurrentGCThread [stack: 0x40f5c000,0x40fdd000] [id=6679]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000c

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000008, ECX=0x0bf5e510, EDX=0x42d6dcb0
ESP=0x40fdc150, EBP=0x40fdc168, ESI=0x40fdc200, EDI=0xa19e9640
EIP=0x062c75f5, CR2=0x0000000c, EFLAGS=0x00210206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x40fdc150)
0x40fdc150: 40fdc200 71c70000 0815a748 0815a704
0x40fdc160: a19e9640 40fdc200 40fdc198 062c74cb
0x40fdc170: 40fdc200 a19e9640 0bf5e510 0bf5e510
0x40fdc180: 080ea6f0 40fdc200 00000010 a19e9640
0x40fdc190: ad38a000 40fdc200 40fdc1c8 0629efaa
0x40fdc1a0: 40fdc200 a19e9640 00000100 00000100
0x40fdc1b0: 0815ab00 40fdc200 40fdc2b8 40fdc200
0x40fdc1c0: 080ea5f0 0815a638 40fdc2b8 062c2905

Instructions: (pc=0x062c75f5)
0x062c75e5: 53 83 ec 0c 8b 7d 0c 8b 75 08 8b 47 04 8d 58 08
0x062c75f5: 8b 53 04 89 d1 c1 f9 02 85 d2 7e 6f b8 04 00 00

Stack: [0x40f5c000,0x40fdd000], sp=0x40fdc150, free space=512k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V [libjvm.so+0x2c75f5]
V [libjvm.so+0x2c74cb]
V [libjvm.so+0x29efaa]
V [libjvm.so+0x2c2905]
V [libjvm.so+0x2bb461]
V [libjvm.so+0x2c9ef5]
V [libjvm.so+0x506929]
C [libpthread.so.0+0x52ab]
```

Comment: serverfault.com is still private beta... so I might be a good fit... in the future.

Comment: This seems to be fixed with Sun JDK 6u20.

Comment: @ReneS - *"... bug request to Sun never returned a response."*.  It is a Bug REPORT not a support request.  They explicitly state that you should not expect any response ... and these days you have to acknowledge this before they'll let you submit the bug report!  If you need support, you should sign up for an Oracle Java support contract.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar JVM dump.
The cause was the lack of memory/swap space in the Solaris zone.
Running the same program in 64-bit mode (ie with Java option -d64), the error was more explicit :

`A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:`

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 395856 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?`

`Internal Error (allocation.cpp:272), pid=10847, tid=32
  Error: Chunk::new`

`JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

There have been several bug fixes related to GC crashes since 6u13 .. here are a few:

- [6897143](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6897143) - Stress test crashes during HeapInspection using ParallelGC.
- [6845368](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6845368) - large objects cause a crash or unexpected exception
- [6840775](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6840775) - Multiple JVM crashes seen with 1.6.0_10 through early access of 1.6.0_14 - possibly related to GC
- [6806226](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6806226) - Signed integer overflow in growable array code causes JVM crash

I suggest using at least Java 6 Update 18 (u18).